# How to generate all possible shortcuts of a word in Java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, shortcut

Is there an algorithm for generating all the possible shortcuts of a word?
For example:

input: `Arteria`

output:

```
Arter.
Art.
Ar.
Aa.
aa.
a.
```

For Advanced example:

input: `Contrast Agents`

output:

```
C.A.
ca.
contr.a.
contr.ag.
```

**EDIT** based on negative reactions, because of not deeply specified rules.

Rules for simple accronyms generation:

1. The accronyms should end up with consonant
2. The accronyms should be created from syllables of the word. Where we can divide the syllables into:

   -**One syllable words** known as monosyllabic:
   Cat, dog, car, sky.

   -**Two syllables words** known as disyllabic:
   Ho-tel, Po-em, Chor-us.

   -**Three syllables words** known as trisyllabic:
   Beau-ti-ful, met-a-phor, po-e-try.

   -**More than three syllables words** known as polysyllabic:
   Ox-y-mor-on.

So it should apply both rules at the same time. Thanks!

The advanced rules are for latin and I will post another question for em.

Thnanks!

Comment: What are the rules for something being an abbreviation of another word?

Comment: In the simplest case It should end with a consonant but the problem is that I am going to generate medical terms so there are no specific rules for latin shortcuts. It should be connected to some dictionary probably

Comment: The given example is hard to understand. How can aa be short for Arteria. Also, what do you mean by "all possible"

Comment: If there are no general rules, how about you look for some online medical abbreviations database and try to use that?

Comment: So the problem here is that I have to generate abbreviations in czech language, which mostly end up with consonant, also i have to generate accronyms for latin.

Comment: The question was devided into 2 parts -> Simple generation and Advanced. As I see the advanced one is quite complex so igonre it. You have pointed me to the right direciton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point for you might be, to get all possible combinations of words / single chars.

From that point on, you could try to to build a more specific algorithm that takes in account your specific needs.

As a very basic implementation of combining words, you could try the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Shortcut {

    public Shortcut() {
        printMultipleWordShortcuts("Contrast Agents");
    }

    private String[] getSingleWordShortcuts(String input) {

        String[] possibleCombinations = new String[ input.length() ];

        // Iterate backwards over the input string and get possible
        // combinations
        for(int i = input.length(); i > 0; i--) {

            possibleCombinations[i-1] = input.substring(0, i);

        }

        return possibleCombinations;

    }

    private void printMultipleWordShortcuts(String input) {

        // Split the input string, assuming that the input words are separated by spaces
        String[] splitWords = input.split(" ");

        List<String[]> allCombinations = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get possible combinations for every split word.
        for(int i = 0; i < splitWords.length; i++) {
            allCombinations.add(getSingleWordShortcuts(splitWords[i]));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < allCombinations.size(); i++) {

            for(int j = allCombinations.get(i).length; j > 0; j--) {

                if(i + 1 < allCombinations.size()) {

                    for(int c = 0; c<allCombinations.get(i+1).length; c++) {

                        result.add(allCombinations.get(i)[j-1] + ". " + allCombinations.get(i+1)[c] + ".");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Output all possibilities
        for(String s : result) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above code would be

```
Contrast. A.
Contrast. Ag.
Contrast. Age.
Contrast. Agen.
Contrast. Agent.
Contrast. Agents.
Contras. A.
Contras. Ag.
Contras. Age.
Contras. Agen.
Contras. Agent.
Contras. Agents.
Contra. A.
Contra. Ag.
Contra. Age.
Contra. Agen.
Contra. Agent.
Contra. Agents.
Contr. A.
Contr. Ag.
Contr. Age.
Contr. Agen.
Contr. Agent.
Contr. Agents.
Cont. A.
Cont. Ag.
Cont. Age.
Cont. Agen.
Cont. Agent.
Cont. Agents.
Con. A.
Con. Ag.
Con. Age.
Con. Agen.
Con. Agent.
Con. Agents.
Co. A.
Co. Ag.
Co. Age.
Co. Agen.
Co. Agent.
Co. Agents.
C. A.
C. Ag.
C. Age.
C. Agen.
C. Agent.
C. Agents.
```